# C loss data in structure

Tags: c, function, pointers, buffer

mat.h

```c
struct cell {
    int first;
    int second;
};
struct mat {
    struct cell cells[ROWS][COLS];
};
```

buf.h

```c
struct act {
    void (*fct)();
};

struct q {
    int head;
    int top;
    int size;
    struct act act[];
};
```

buf.c

```c
void add(struct q *b, void (*o)()) {
    b->actions[b->top].fct = o;
    b->top++;
    
    if(b->top == b->size) b->top = 0;
}
```

Main.c

```c
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct q b;
    struct mat m;

    add(&b, init);
    get(&b, &m);
}
```

mat.c

```c
void init(struct q *b, struct mat *m) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
            m->cells[i][j].first = rand() %5;
            m->cells[i][j].second = rand() %2;
        }
    }

    addQueue(b, printM);
}
```

Hi,

I lose data in a structure array when I add function pointer on it. I have a buffer which has a void function pointer. With add function, I add the function address and execute it on main.c. But the problem is, every time I add a new function, there is a cell loses its data (m.cells[0][3].first). I did not find how to avoit it.

Thanks.

Comment: You have a flexible array member in there. This thing needs to be explicitly allocated.

Comment: The last member of `struct q` is a so-called _flexible array member_ with an incomplete array type. The size of `struct q` is the size up to but not including the flexible array member. The `struct q` needs to be embedded in a block of memory (for example, allocated by `malloc` or `realloc`) with sufficient space at the end for the array contents. For example, a block of (suitably aligned) memory of size `offsetof(struct q, fct[10])` would have room for 10 elements.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment, I should have written `offsetof(struct q, act[10])` (or maybe `offsetof(struct q, actions[10])` depending on which part of your posted code is to be believed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable of type `struct q` has no room to store any elements of the *flexible array member* `actions`. In order to be useful, the `struct q` needs to part of a larger block of memory with enough room at the end for the number of required elements.

You could create a function to allocate a `struct q` from dynamically allocated storage with enough space for a specified number of elements:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct q *create_q(int size) {
    struct q *b = malloc(offsetof(struct q, actions[size]));

    if (b) {
        b->head = 0;
        b->top = 0;
        b->size = size;
    }
    return b;
}
```

For consistency, a function can be added to free the `struct q`. That is pretty simple now, but having a specific function allows the internals of the implementation to be changed at a later time if need be:

```
void free_q(struct q *b) {
    free(b);
}
```